# how to check internet connection in android webview and show no internet image not show default error text?

Tags: java, android, webview

how to check internet connection in android webview and show no internet image not show default error text?and i want to show my html file or image for no internet.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    WebView mWebView;

    String URL = "http://www.google.com";

    ProgressBar loadingProgressBar, loadingTitle;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl(URL);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        loadingProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar_Horizontal);

        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

            @Override

            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {

                super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);


                loadingProgressBar.setProgress(newProgress);
                //loadingTitle.setProgress(newProgress);
                // hide the progress bar if the loading is complete

                if (newProgress == 100) {
                    loadingProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                } else {
                    loadingProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }

            }

        });

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            //if Back key pressed and webview can navigate to previous page
            mWebView.goBack();
            // go back to previous page
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            finish();
            // finish the activity
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {


        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You may need to use a service/broadcast receiver for network status changes.

Comment: Try this in the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20989485/how-to-show-message-if-no-internet-available-in-my-android-webview